# Unit testing Spring Service with the connections to Mapper and Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm wondering what's the best approach to test the Service layer when I use Mapper and Repository inside my Service:

```java
public ExpenseDto create(NewExpenseDto newExpenseDto) {

    ExpenseEntity expenseEntity = expenseMapper.fromNewDtoToEntity(newExpenseDto);
    ExpenseEntity savedExpenseEntity = expenseRepository.save(expenseEntity);
    ExpenseDto expenseDto = expenseMapper.fromEntityToDto(savedExpenseEntity);

    return expenseDto;
}
```

I have written a test like this below, but I'm not sure if it's the best way - in accordance with the rules of programming.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ExpenseServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ExpenseRepository expenseRepository;
    @Mock
    private ExpenseMapper expenseMapper;
    @InjectMocks
    private ExpenseService expenseService ;

    @Test
    void givenNewExpenseDto_whenNewExpense_thenExpenseDtoNotNull() {
        //Given
        NewExpenseDto newExpenseDto = new NewExpenseDto();
        ExpenseEntity expenseEntity = new ExpenseEntity();
        ExpenseDto expenseDto = new ExpenseDto();

        //When
        when(expenseMapper.fromNewDtoToEntity(any())).thenReturn(expenseEntity);
        when(expenseRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(expenseEntity);
        when(expenseMapper.fromEntityToDto(any())).thenReturn(expenseDto);
        ExpenseDto savedExpenseDto = expenseService.create(newExpenseDto);

        //Then
        assertNotNull(savedExpenseDto, "Saved ExpenseDto is null");
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have some remarks of your test :

- it is better to test your method by passing to it an instance with parameters, so you can ensure that your instance is saved with the right values.

  `NewExpenseDto newExpenseDto = new NewExpenseDto(param1, param2, param3);`
- you should specify parameters for your mocks `when(expenseMapper.fromNewDtoToEntity(any()))` becomes :

`when(expenseMapper.fromNewDtoToEntity(new NewExpenseDto(eq(param1), eq(param2), eq(param3))))`

- you should not assert only on the nullability of your instance but also on the fields of  `savedExpenseDto`

  `assertEquals(expenseRepository.getParam1(), value1);`
- you should also verify the call with right values of the `save` method of your repository `expenseRepository`

  `verify(expenseRepository).save(new ExpenseEntity(param1, param2, param3))`

for this I suppose that you override hash and equals method for `ExpenseEntity`

Comment: if you find my response useful can you vote for it, please